# jQuery Rotate Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, jquery-rotate

I'm using [jQuery Rotate plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryRotate) to rotate items. It works, but I experienced some problems.

I have that code:

```
<input type="text" name="np_angle" id="np_angle" size="2" maxlength="4" value="<?=$userinfo->np_angle?>" onchange="$('#np_drag').rotate(this.value)" />

<div id="np_drag" style="color:<?=$userinfo->np_color?>; font-size:<?=$userinfo->np_size?>px;position:absolute;top:<?=$userinfo->np_y?>px;left:<?=$userinfo->np_x?>px" class="draggable np_drag">
<?=$userinfo->np_text?>
</div>

<script>$("#np_drag").rotate(<?=$userinfo->np_angle?>);</script>
```

The problem is on input onchange. When I change it, #np_drag don't rotate. But when value is static (e.g. `onchange="$('#np_drag').rotate(45)"`
It works.

Why? How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the statement `$('#np_drag').rotate(this.value)`, `this` will refer to `np_drag` and I believe you want it to refer to the value of `np_angle`. Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="np_angle" id="np_angle" size="2" maxlength="4" value="<?=$userinfo->np_angle?>" />

<script>$('#np_angle').bind('change', function(e){$('#np_drag').rotate($('#np_angle').val())});" </script>
```

Comment: and adding parseInt($('#np_angle').val())

Answer (score 1):

Select it with an `id`

```
...  id="my-id" onchange="$('#np_drag').rotate($('#my-id).val())" ...
```

Additionally, you might want to bind the `onchange` event via the dom-ready function instead of writing it in the HTML source

Comment: But when I try `onchange="alert(this.value);"` It alerts me the value I entered in np_angle.